# Obtener variable del code-behind en javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, script, nav, tab

Tengo el siguiente código en javascript y el mismo funciona bien. Deseo que al momento que detecte el click en esta tab (tab número 2) verifique si una variable que creo en el code-behind esta en true o false.

```js
$("#map_canvas_tab").on("click", function () {

     alert("tab no 2 is clicked....");
});
```

Deseo colocar algo como esto pero se que esta errado

```js
$("#map_canvas_tab").on("click", function () {
    if (variable == true){    
        alert("tab no 2 is clicked....");
    }
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué sería el code-behind, el backend? Podría agregar más detalles a la pregunta sobre cómo o dónde se crea o existe la variable a la que se requiere acceder al hacer clic en esa pestaña.

Comment: Se supone que **variable** existe de modo global previamente, definida con **var**, porque sino no entrará en la función que estas definiendo y será **undefined**